# Why analytics from android to ios are too different?

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

The active users of android are very different from those of ios:

iOS:
[image: ios-users]

Android:
[image: android-users]

But the income is very similar, I receive € 45 in Android and € 30 in IOS.

Of course I have integrated the sdk because if not I would not receive any statistics.

Is it possible in iOS that we have to give some special permission to receive the statistics well?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the language in the screenshot. Can you elaborate your question? Thanks

Comment: 3 Labels that appear on screenshots are the same, on this order are, Monthly, Weekly and daily user actives.

Comment: Thanks. There is no special permission in Analytics on iOS to receive the statistics. Instead of comparing the two platforms, I think you should compare the iOS numbers to iTunes Connect to verify whether it is correct.

Comment: Thank you @adbitx !! In iTunes Connect appear 1.32K units... more than firebase analytics... how is it possible? On Firebase analytics section latest Release, last update was 5 versions ago, how is it possible?

Comment: Do you have any subscriptions or non-consumable IAP on iOS? What's your current Analytics version? Can you update to the latest SDK version (5.0) and check the number after a week?